# How to run codeception on eclipse

Tags: eclipse, codeception

I would like to set up Codeception and run automation test on eclipse. Could you please let me the way to setup Codeception with eclipe?

Answer (score 0):

After you have a php project and already download 'codecept.phar' to root folder of the project, run the command at root folder: $php codecept.phar bootstrap

Setup Codeception in Eclipse:

1. Open Eclipse, select Help/Install New Software (If your eclipse does not support PHP).
2. Search "PHP Development Tool"
3. Click Install, follow steps to install
4. Restart Eclipse
5. File/New project
6. Select PHP Project from list
7. Create new or select from existing project. ex: C:\wamp\www\wordpress

Then you can create new test file (Cept/Cest) and type some command to see auto complete of your command.

Hope it help.